# Deployment to Azure with Kudu and cUrl

Tags: azure, kudu

I'm trying to deploy an Azure app from a script.
Azure has been set up for external git repository deployment.
I've set the deploy key (Azure's SSH public key) into Gitlab

The following works

```
curl -X POST 
     -H "Content-type: application/json"
     -d "{'format':'basic', 'url':'https://GITLABUSER:GITLABUSERPASSWORD@gitlab.com/MYTEAM/MYGIT.git'}"
     -u "AZUREUSERNAME:AZUREPASSWORD"  
     https://MYSITE.scm.azurewebsites.net/deploy
```

is there a way to not specify the Gitlab user and password in the request since Azure already knows the address of the Git to pull from ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it won't work without username/password, per the [code](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/blob/d3282bb09fe04e0b28941c59e07e2217b85e7961/Kudu.Services/ServiceHookHandlers/GitlabHqHandler.cs#L53-L60) which explicitly checks for their presence when it handles GitLab.

The better way to do this is to use the ARM sync API, instead of talking directly to the (lower level) Kudu API. e.g. there is a sample [here](https://github.com/davidebbo/AzureWebsitesSamples/blob/19487e3622b98fa16a6e28b6b5f357270a4b434a/PowerShell/HelperFunctions.ps1#L393-L396) on how to call it with PowerShell:

```
Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites -Name $SiteName -Action sync -ApiVersion $WebAppApiVersion -Force
```

And you can call the same API via any mechanism that supports making ARM API calls.

#### Previous (incorrect) answer

Try passing the ssh url instead of https in the payload. I believe it will do the right thing.

Comment: Trying to change the https url to 'url':'git@gitlab.com/MYTEAM/MYGIT.git' yields to an error "Repository url &#39;git@gitlab.com/MYTEAM/MYGIT.git&#39; is invalid."

Comment: You're right, that doesn't work. I modified the answer to describe an alternate technique.

Comment: Could try that, need to have powershell installed on my Docker build image though.

Comment: PowerShell was just an example. You can call that same ARM API by any mean (xplat CLI, raw rest, ...).